# Detecting mouse support

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouse

This is the opposite of detecting touch support in browsers. How can I detect if a browser has mouse support? Chrome for desktop should return true, Safari for iPad should return false.

I'm thinking that mobile browsers will return false positives for the usual detection tricks.

Answer (score 1):

In browsers that use Touch Events:

`var clickEvent = ('ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click');`
is basically saying “if the device support touch, only listen to touchend and not click” – which, on a multi-input device, immediately shuts out any interaction via mouse, trackpad or keyboard.

This article discusses your question in details [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/)

Another insightful article [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/)

But, it all depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you should be able to test if it has touch support, then take the reverse. I could be wrong, but as far as I know, browsers that don't support touch events will support mouse events, and vice versa, as the difference between these two is usually mobile vs. regular browsers.

EDIT: Another possibility might be using onmousemove in the same way you use ontouchmove to detect touch capability. However, I'm not sure if mobile browsers would register onmousemove.

Comment: What about someone using an all-in-one with a touch screen and mouse?

Comment: I suppose your site wouldn't work the way you really wanted it to with that, but whether it warrants a fix depends on how common those browsers are, what he's doing with it, and whether people on those devices would want to use his site. This is one possible workaround.

Comment: This won't work. Desktop Firefox returns true for touch-detection. They use the same code-base on desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This method checks if the `Touch` object exists without using events. If it doesn't, you have a mouse. I think that's the easiest way to do it. It will return `false` on the rare device that has touch and a mouse, so you'll have to decide if that affects your design or not.

```js
function hasTouch() {
    return (typeof Touch == 'object' );
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/ux89v/

Script:

```js
function hasTouch() {
    return (typeof Touch == 'object' );
};

document.getElementById( 'touch' ).textContent = 'Mouse: ' + !hasTouch();
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="touch"></div>
```

Comment: Devices with mouse and touch are going to become less and less rare over the coming months/years with touch screens starting to appear on laptops and desktops.. I don't see why Touch would necessarily not be an object on these devices?

Comment: @Jonhoo Yes exactly. I was just debugging strange behavior in my hobby project web application, and noticed that my Javascript code believes that my 17'' laptop with touch screen is ... a mobile phone or something like that. Since it has a touch screen.